# MySQL: How to use the result of one INSERT in another INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to use the resulting key of one insert, in another insert. Is this possible with MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) returns the id of last inserted record  you can use that one

> Retrieves the ID generated for an
>   AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous
>   query (usually INSERT).